# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null" Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Good evening,

I am trying to implement a full screen navigation however I keep getting the following error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null"**

I cannot find the cause of this problem despite removing all unnecessary JS that were present on this empty theme template. I have also double checked I have added everything in correctly.

The live URL is [here.](http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/CharlyNew/) The JS I am trying to implement is from [this site.](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/)

```
(function() {
var container = document.querySelector( 'div.container' ),
    triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
    overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
    closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
    transEndEventNames = {
        'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
        'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
        'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
        'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
    support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

function toggleOverlay() {
    if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
        classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.remove( container, 'overlay-open' );
        classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
        var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
        };
        if( support.transitions ) {
            overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
        }
        else {
            onEndTransitionFn();
        }
    }
    else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
        classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
        classie.add( container, 'overlay-open' );
    }
}

triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Thanks to anyone who might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: it is because you do not have a div with class `container` on your page.

Comment: i just downloaded the example from the site and they indeed have a div with class `container`. i think it doesn't have anything to do with `overlay` @mevius

Comment: can you try adding a `container` class to your `wrapper` div @CharlyAnderson?

Comment: Your js file is included at the beginning, and the part which is trying to get the elements is executed immediatelly. I suggest you to execute that part after document.ready . 

(function() {
 var container = document.querySelector( 'div.container' ),
  triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
  overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
  closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );